Are functions from a non metrizable general topological space into $\mathbb{R}$ continous under the ring structure?
That is, would continous functions from a general topological space X be closed under field addition, multiplication and so on?
Supposing $X$ is metrizable the proof is pretty doable, and example of it being closed under multiplication is shown here : Proof verification: the product of two continuous functions is continuous.
However, how do we prove continuity when it's from a general topological space?

Here is what I got so far, we have $f,g: X \to Y$ is continous and must prove that $fg$ and $f+g$  is continous.
Since the sum seems simpler I start with that,
Let's suppose try to prove that $f+g$ is continous, we must show that $\text{preim}_{f+g} ( B_{\epsilon} (y) ) = U_x$ where $U_x$ is an open set in $X$ given that $\text{preim}_{f} ( B_{\epsilon} (y) ) = U_1$   and $\text{preim}_{g} ( B_{\epsilon} (y) ) = U_2$
Now this seems quite intractable. Could someone advise on how to proceed further?

Your title question is not what you're asking in the body.

This is very standard. Multiplication and addition are continuous in the reals. The diagonal product of continuous functions is continuous. Composition of continuous functions is continuous.

All you have to prove is that addition $a : \mathbb R \times \mathbb R \to \mathbb R, a(x,y) = x  + y$, and multiplication $m : \mathbb R \times \mathbb R \to \mathbb R, m(x,y) = x  \cdot y$, are continuous.

As mentioned, all you need to prove is what @KritikerderElche mentions in their comment, and that is easily done with $\epsilon$, $\delta$.  (This may also be found on this very site.) From there, you can prove that pointwise sums and products of continuous maps $X \to \mathbb{R}$ are continuous directly from properties of the product topology.

Alright, from the hints I got what to do. For those with the same question, here is the solution:
Consider the following commutative diagram of topological spaces:
[]
where,

$i: x \to (x,x)$

$p: (a,b) \to (f(a),g(b) )$

$q: (a,b) \to ab$


The goal is to prove continuity of $ q \circ p \circ i $. We do it in steps, but firstly, a lemma.

The universal property of product topologies

If all objects in the above diagram are topological spaces, then it simply states that $f_1: Y \to X_1$ and $f_2: Y \to X_2$ being continous implies existence of a unique and conitnous $f$.

1. i
Consider the constant function $f: X \to X, x \mapsto x$. This is continous in any topology. From the diagram,

we get that the function $f(x,x)=(x,x)$ must be continous.

2. $p$
We have the following diagram:

Where $ u: (a,b) \mapsto f(a)$ and $v: (a,b) \mapsto g(b)$. We can see both them as composite $u= f( \pi_1  \big( (a,b) \big) )$ and $v= g(  \pi_2  \big( (a,b) \big))$, where $ \pi_1 : X \times X \to X, (a,b) \mapsto a$ and $ \pi_1 : X \times X \to X, (a,b) \mapsto b$. Since projections are continous, and we were given that $f,g$ are continous composition are continous.
Hence, $u,v$ is continous which then leads to $p$ being continous by the universal property.

3. $q$
Well.. this one is obvious. It would also be continous if it were an addition.

Finally, the entire composition is continous.
